# Using XSLT for recursively merging XHTML file into one XHTML file

Tags: xslt, xhtml, merge

I'm trying to create an XSL stylesheet which allows one to merge the XHTML files that are referred from another XHTML file. In turn, any XHTML files referred from the referred files should be merged too, and so on. Thus, it should be possible to recursively merge all XHTML referred directly or indirectly by a starting XHTML file into one XHTML file. The references are striclty hierarchical.

Example:

File a.html:

```
<html>
    <body>Text1<br/><a href="b.html">Link</a></body>
</html>
```

File b.html:

```
<html>
    <body>Text2<br/><a href="c.html">Link</a></body>
</html>
```

File c.html:

```
<html>
    <body>Text3<br/></body>
</html>
```

Resulting merged file when starting with a.html:

```
<html>
    <body>Text1<br/>Text2<br/>Text3<br/></body>
</html>
```

I don't know exactly how to solve that problem with XSLT. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: +1 - Good question with nice short examples.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `document()` function, as shown in this stylesheet:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--IDENTITY TRANSFORM-->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@href)/html/body/node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with your 3 html files, and using `a.html` as the input, results in this output:

```html
<html>
  <body>Text1<br/>Text2<br/>Text3<br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, what really makes this possible is the identity transform. It passes anything not matched by another template unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be a bit tricky, but check out the `document()` function.

- http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/func_document.asp

The examples I've seen show how to include another document in your output, but I didn't see any examples that would let you begin transforming that document during the same invocation.  But I didn't try it out myself either.

If it doesn't work out that `document()` lets you recurse your transform into the other documents, you could invoke your transform in a loop, and write your transform to be called repeatedly.  Then you'll need some way to check for when you can stop transforming.

One way to know when you should stop would be to do a diff between your source and target documents.

Another way would be to place an element at the top of your document if any sub-documents were found, and remove it when none are found.  Then just check for the presence of this element.

But maybe there is a way to continue transforming through included sub-documents.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
  "document(@href)/*/body/node()"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the file "a.html":**

```
<html>
    <body>Text1<br/><a href="b.html">Link</a></body>
</html>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<html><body>Text1<br/>Text2<br/>Text3<br/></body></html>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule copies every node "as-is".
2. The only overriding template matches any `a` element.
3. Within this template the processing of the document pointed to in the `href` attribute of the `a` element is initiated. It is essential that we use the standard XSLT function `document()`.